# One table with multiple pivots tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

these are relations in my models :

- Medecine belongsto many Pharmacologic and Pharmacologic belongsto many Medecine
- Medecine belongsto many Therapeutic and Therapeutic belongsto many Medecine
- Medecine belongsto many Galenic and Galenic belongsto many Medecine
- Medecine belongsto many AdministrationMode and AdministrationMode belongsto many Medecine
- Medecine belongsto many ActivePrinciple and ActivePrinciple belongsto many Medecine

Pharmacologic is working well and faster in all case (loadind is normal) -:)

My problem is there, when i execute this type of query in my controller for other relations :

```
$Pharmacologic = Pharmacologic ::Find(1);

$Medecines= $Pharmacologic ->medecines()->orderBy('field1', 'asc')
->paginate(10);

return view('page', compact('Medecines'));
```

Migrations

1. Pharmacologic and medecine pivot

```php
Schema::create('pharmaco_medecine', function(Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('medecine _id')->unsigned(); $table->foreign('medecine _id') ->references('id')->on('tbl_medecine') ->onDelete('cascade');
$table->integer('pharmaco_id')->unsigned(); $table->foreign('pharmaco_id') ->references('id')->on('tbl_pharmaco') ->onDelete('cascade'); });
```

2. Therapeutic and medecine pivot

```php
Schema::create('therapeutic_medecine', function(Blueprint $table) {

$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('medecine_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('medecine_id')
      ->references('id')->on('tbl_medecine')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->integer('therapeutic_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('therapeutic_id')
      ->references('id')->on('tbl_therapeutic')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

3. Galenic and medecine pivot

```php
Schema::create('gal_medecine, function(Blueprint $table) {

$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('medecine_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('medecine_id')
      ->references('id')->on('tbl_medecine')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->integer('gal_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('gal_id')
      ->references('id')->on('tbl_gal')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

4. AdministrationMode and medecine pivot

```php
Schema::create('medecine_admin_mode', function(Blueprint $table) {

$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('medecine_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('medecine_id')
      ->references('id')->on('tbl_medecine')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
$table->integer('admin_mode_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('admin_mode_id')
      ->references('id')->on('tbl_adminmode')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

5. ActivePrinciple and medecine pivot

```php
Schema::create('medecine_active_princip', function(Blueprint $table) {

$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('medecine_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('medecine_id')
      ->references('id')->on('tbl_medecine')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->integer('active_princip_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('active_princip_id')
      ->references('id')->on('tbl_activeprincip')
      ->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

The view is generating data results without any error but is STILL LOADING FOR SEVERAL MINUTES. What im missing ?

Thnx and sorry for this long post

Models

Medecine

```
class Medecine extends Model
{
    protected $table='tbl_medecine';


        public function pharmacologics() 
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pharmacologic');

    }

            public function therapeutics() 
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Therapeutic');

    }

                public function galenics() 
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Galenic');

    }

                public function administrationmodes() 
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\AdministrationMode');

    }

                public function activeprinciples() 
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ActivePrinciple');

    }
}
```

Pharmacologic

```
class Pharmacologic extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table='tbl_pharmacologic';

    public function medecines() 
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Medecine');

    }
}
```

And so on ...

Comment: Have you tried debugging the queries so you can see the sql that is generated? see https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel

Comment: Thnx for your quick response Sven, im working on it.

Comment: Can you show your models? Are you eager loading relationships in your medecine model? (Did you add a $with array there?). It should become a bit faster if you put Pharmacologic::with('medecines')->Find(1); in your controller. But please check your models

Comment: Hi @EduardoPacios ! Thank you but i didnt use $with array but let me try it. Heres my models :

Comment: What do you mean by "The view is generating data results without any error but is STILL LOADING FOR SEVERAL MINUTES"?

Comment: @EduardoPacios , thank you. It's more faster with " with ".